# SVG file script not working in html

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

What I want to do is create an svg file in which I have 2 cylinders, one inside the other representing tank and liquid. I want the inside cylinder to move according to the percentage of liquid given. I have achieved this and the code is working fine in js fiddle. But when I am trying to integrate the svg as file into the html the inner cylinder is not working.

Please find the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/7op7re9j/3/

**Code used in jsfiddle:**

```
<div class="progressBar">
<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->
 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1" fill="#fff" id="canvas_background"/>
 </g>
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
        .stop1 { stop-color: grey; }
        .stop2 { stop-color: black; stop-opacity: 0; }
        .stop3 { stop-color: grey; }
      ]]>
  </style>
  <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
   <stop offset="0%" class="stop1"/>
   <stop offset="50%" class="stop2"/>
   <stop offset="100%" class="stop3"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>

  <path d="m527,77.53519c0,33.2677 -102.30249,60.23117 -228.49918,60.23117m228.49918,-60.23117l0,0c0,33.2677 -102.30249,60.23117 -228.49918,60.23117c-126.19745,0 -228.50072,-26.96347 -228.50072,-60.23117m0,0l0,0c0,-33.28308 101.42944,-62.78519 227.62694,-62.78519c126.19666,0 229.37296,29.50211 229.37296,62.78519l0,240.97189c0,33.26648 -102.30249,60.24292 -228.49918,60.24292c-126.19745,0 -228.50072,-26.97644 -228.50072,-60.24292l0,-240.97189z" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-opacity="null" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="null" fill="rgb(255, 215, 0)" id="svg_2"/>
  <rect height="225" width="10" y="90.77" x="51.75" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-opacity="null" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="null" fill="#fff68f" id="svg_3"/>
  <rect height="13.5" width="10" y="319.77" x="51.75" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-opacity="null" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="null" fill="#ff0000" id="svg_7"/>
  <rect height="13.5" width="10" y="73.77" x="51.75" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-opacity="null" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="null" fill="#ff0000" id="svg_8"/>
  <path d="m527,71.58089c0,34.05788 -102.75073,61.6671 -229.49994,61.6671m229.49994,-61.6671l0,0c0,34.05788 -102.75073,61.6671 -229.49994,61.6671c-126.74753,0 -229.50006,-27.60924 -229.50006,-61.6671m0,0l0,0c0,-34.0567 102.75255,-61.66643 229.50006,-61.66643c126.74921,0 229.49994,27.60972 229.49994,61.66643l0,246.66637c0,34.05798 -102.75073,61.66721 -229.49994,61.66721c-126.74753,0 -229.50006,-27.60922 -229.50006,-61.66721l0,-246.66637z" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="5.5" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="null" fill="url(#Gradient1)" id="svg_5"/>
  <path d="m171.4028,276.6062l314.99991,0c-34.79343,0 -63.00003,103.42236 -63.00003,231c0,127.57776 28.2066,231 63.00003,231l-314.99991,0l0,0c-34.79411,0 -63.00003,-103.42224 -63.00003,-231c0,-127.57767 28.20592,-231 63.00003,-231z" transform="rotate(-90 297.403 507.606)" stroke-width="0.005" stroke-opacity="null" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="null" fill="#fff" id="svg_9"/>
 </g>
 <script><![CDATA[
  var path = document.getElementById('svg_2');
  var liqpercent=50;
  var cal=100-liqpercent;
  var segments = path.pathSegList;
  segments.getItem(0).y = 77+(2.4*cal);
]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

Comment: hi..i tried running the code in ie instead of chrome and it was working fine. but i want it to work in both the browsers. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

`pathSegList` was removed from Chrome some time ago. You should not use it anymore. Chrome broke the web with this move but they did it anyway.

There is a complete polyfill for pathSegList here: https://github.com/progers/pathseg

So when you include that, it shoulds start working again